# Trigger to find deleted record and update the values to other table using pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I want to create a trigger so that when an employee  record is deleted, the record details need to be inserted into a table called Employee_archive along with the deleted date.

```
EMPLOYEE:                                       EMPLOYEE_ARCHIVE:
EMPID     NUMBER   PRIMARY KEY          EMPID      NUMBER    PRIMARY KEY
EMPNAME VARCHAR2(25)                    EMPNAME  VARCHAR2(25)
MANAGERID NUMBER                        MANAGERID  NUMBER
                                                DELETED_DATE  DATE
```

The code I tried writing is -

```
create or replace trigger check_delete
after delete on employee
for each row
declare
v_id employee.empid%type;
v_name employee.empname%type;
v_magid employee.managerid%type;
begin
select empid, empname, managerid into v_id, v_name, v_magid from employee;
insert into employee_archive(empid, empname, managerid, deleted_date)
values(v_id, v_name, v_magid, sysdate);
end;
/
```

In the output, the trigger is created, but I have an error as follows -

```
DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPID=101
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table P11649.EMPLOYEE is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "P11649.CHECK_DELETE", line 6
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'P11649.CHECK_DELETE'
```

I am unable to understand that, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh, no - you can't access (it is `SELECT ... FROM` in your code) the table you're deleting from *right now* - it is *mutating* (as the error suggests). Do it differently:

An empty archive table:

```
SQL> select * from employee_archive;

no rows selected
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger check_delete
  2    before delete on employee
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    insert into employee_archive(empno, ename, job, sal, datum)
  6      values (:old.empno, :old.ename, :old.job, :old.sal, sysdate);
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> delete from employee where ename = 'KING';

1 row deleted.

SQL> select * from employee_archive;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL DATUM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------------------
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT      10000 21.10.2020 11:48:31

SQL>
```